# Showing that the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is continuous using the $\epsilon \delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

I am attempting to prove that $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is continuous. Here's my attempt so far.

In order to prove that $f(x)$ is continuous, it is necessary to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{c}{1+c^2}|<\epsilon$ when $|x-c|<\delta$.

I first start by working with the left side of the inequality. We can say that $$|\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{c}{1+c^2}| = \frac{|x-c+c^2x-cx^2|}{|(1+x^2)(1+c^2)|}$$ After this we can use the triangle inequality to say, $$\frac{|x-c+c^2x-cx^2|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}\leq \frac{|x-c|+|c^2x|+|-cx^2|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}$$
Now we can break the function into 3 terms $$\frac{|x-c|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}+\frac{|c^2x|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}+\frac{|x^2c|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}$$
Then we use the fact that $$\frac{c^2x}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}<1$$ which can be applied to the last 2 terms using the same logic. This gives $$\frac{|x-c|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}+2$$
Now we want to isloate $|x-c|$ in order to solve for $\delta$.
I have
$$\frac{|x-c|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}<\epsilon-2$$. This is where I get stuck. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that I can $\frac{1}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}<1$ so $|x-c|<\epsilon-2$? This doesn't seem right but it's just a thought.

Comment: You have two terms in your bound that can't be made arbitrarily small as $x \to c$.  You need a better bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $c \neq 0$, use the bound

$$\tag{*}\left|\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{c}{1+c^2}\right| = \frac{|x-c+c^2x-cx^2|}{(1+x^2)(1+c^2)} =\frac{|x-c+c^2x-cx^2+c^3 - c^3|}{(1+x^2)(1+c^2)} \\ \leqslant\frac{|x-c|+c^2|x-c|+|c||x^2-c^2|}{(1+x^2)(1+c^2)}= \frac{1+c^2+|c||x+c|}{(1+x^2)(1+c^2)}|x-c|$$

If $|x-c| < \frac{|c|}{2}$, then, since $|x| - |c| \leqslant |x-c|$, we have $\frac{|c|}{2} < |x| < \frac{3|c|}{2}$ and

$$\tag{**}|x+c| \leqslant |x|+|c| <\frac{5|c|}{2}, \quad 1+x^2 > 1+ \frac{c^2}{2}$$

Bounding on the RHS of (*) with (**), we get

$$\left|\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{c}{1+c^2}\right| < \frac{1+c^2 + \frac{5c^2}{2}}{\left(1 + \frac{c^2}{2}\right)(1+c^2)}|x-c|$$

You should be able to finish from here by finding $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-c| < \min(\delta, \frac{|c|^2}{2})$, then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.

Handle the case where $c=0$ separately.

Comment: You seem to have dropped a $|c|$ in the numerator, or does that disappear? Also, where exactly does the min{$\delta$,$\frac{|c|^2}{2}$) come from? Thanks for the response!

Comment: For the first  question the third term is bounded as $|c||x+c| < |c| \frac{5|c|}{2} = \frac{5c^2}{2}$ which appears in the RHS numerator.

Comment: For the second, we want to show that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ for $x$ close to $c$.  We start with $|x-c| < \frac{|c|}{2}$ to get the bound shown above -- that is $|f(x) - f(c)| \leqslant B_c |x-c|$ where $B_c = \frac{1+c^2 + \frac{5c^2}{2}}{\left(1 + \frac{c^2}{2}\right)(1+c^2)}$. Then take $|x-c| < \frac{\epsilon}{B_c}$ as well.

Comment: So if $|x-c| < \min(\epsilon/B_c, |c|/2)$ we get $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Sorry to bring up more questions, I understand your answer, I just don't understand why my simplification doesn't work. What prevents us from saying that those other terms that the terms that are less than one can't be plugging in for. Thanks again!

Comment: With your bounds you showed that $|f(x) - f(c)| \leqslant \frac{|x-c|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|}+2$.  The first term on the RHS is nonnegative so all you have shown is that $|f(x) - f(c)| \leqslant \alpha$ where $\alpha \geqslant 2$ for all $x$. OK -- now how would that show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can choose $x$ close to $c$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.  You can't.

Comment: But lets follow your argument.  You say suppose the LHS is less than $\epsilon > 0$ and rearrange to get $\frac{|x-c|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|} < \epsilon -2$.  The $\epsilon-\delta$ argument has to work for ALL $\epsilon > 0$.  What if we use $\epsilon = 1$?  Then we  have $\frac{|x-c|}{|1+x^2||1+c^2|} < -1$.  But the LHS is nonnegative - so it is impossible.